# Sprite rotation with touch pad

Tags: libgdx

I'am having a issue or just don't know how to make it to work so everything is seen in image.

```
rotation = lerp(rotation, realRotation, delta / 2);
```

[IMAGE GIF](http://server.edgu.lt/ign/2017-03-14_18-39-54.gif)

Answer (score 0):

You want to linearly interpolate ship rotation between a particular angle(set by TouchPad) to original(default) value.

I am trying to achieve your requirement in my code.

```
public class TestGame1 extends Game {

    Stage stage;
    Touchpad touchpad;
    Image image;
    float angle=0;
    Texture shipTex;

    @Override
    public void create() {
        stage=new Stage();

        image=new Image(shipTex=new Texture("ship1.png"));
        image.setPosition(300,300);
        image.setSize(100,107);
        image.setOrigin(50,53);

        Skin skin=new Skin(Gdx.files.internal("skin/uiskin.json"));
        touchpad=new Touchpad(10,skin);
        touchpad.setPosition(100,100);
        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);

        stage.addActor(image);
        stage.addActor(touchpad);
    }

    @Override
    public void render() {

        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0,0,0,1);

        stage.act();
        stage.draw();

        float knobX=touchpad.getKnobPercentX();
        float knobY=touchpad.getKnobPercentY();

        if(knobX!=0 && knobY!=0) {
            float radAngle = MathUtils.atan2(knobY, knobX);
            angle = MathUtils.radiansToDegrees * radAngle;
            angle -= 90;

            if (angle > 360)
                angle -= 360;
        }
        else
            angle=MathUtils.lerpAngleDeg(angle,0,Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());

        image.setRotation(angle);
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        stage.dispose();
        shipTex.dispose();
    }
}
```